# Logistic population model question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let the grow rate parameter $k=0.3$, the  carrying capacity $N=3500$. Suppose the initial fox population in the forest is $P(0)=3500$. If 100 foxes die each year. What does the model predict the long term behavior of the fox population? In other word, what does the qualitative analysis of the model yield?

I made the model as following

$(dP/dt)= k(1-P/N)P - 100$

How can I get $P$ from $P(0)$ ?

Comment: Are you sure you write the DEQ correctly? Anyway, you would normally solve the DEQ and use the initial condition to find the particular solution. If this is not possible, you can resort to numerical methods.

Comment: If this is intended to be the "harvesting" version of the logistic equation, which the problem statement seems to suggest, this appears to be correct. (The "-100" is the "harvesting term".)  It can be solved analytically, but it is not separable.

Comment: yes, the qualitative analysis of the logistic is $(dP/dt)=k(1−P/N)P$. However, since 100 fox died every year, so I subtract 100 from the original equation.

Comment: If _only_ the "long-term" behavior is what is being asked for, you can just solve for P in $\frac{dP}{dt}  =  0 $ .  The equilibrium should be an attractor, so having $P(0) > 100$ should take you to the limiting population.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner you are right, That what I thought too. Maybe the author want to say that 100 foxes are harvested each year, but it sounds kinda illegal, so he changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, regarding the long term analysis. You simply state that if the system is stable, the derivative should tend to zero as time tends to infinity, which yields a second order polynomial, which roots are $P_1 = 373.11$ and $P_2 = 3126.89$.

Numerical simulations show that the first equilibrium is unstable, while the second is attractive. This means that if the initial population is stricly greater than $P_1$, the population converges to $P_2$, otherwise everybody dies.

For the analytics, you should checkout [this webpage](http://www.ugrad.math.ubc.ca/coursedoc/math101/notes/moreApps/harvesting.html).

Here is an illustration of the evolution of the population over 80 years:
[image]

Comment: The quick way of establishing the stability of the equilibria is that $\frac{dP}{dt}$ is a "downward-opening" parabola with its intercepts at $P_1$ and $P_2$ .  Since $\frac{dP}{dt}$ changes sign from positive to negative at $P_2$, it is an "attractor"; at $P_1$, the opposite sign change happens, so it is the "repellor".  So all initial populations $P(0) > P_1$ will move toward $P_2$.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Thanks a lot for this interpretation! It seems easy once you understand that! Glad I posted something useless and learned something insightful ;)

Comment: Another way of saying this is that the sign of $\frac{d^2 P}{dt^2}$ at an equilibrium point indicates its character (negative for attractors).  We have $\frac{d^2 P}{dt^2} = 0.3 \cdot (1 - \frac{2P}{3500})$ , which is negative at $P_2$ .

Comment: The graph is not useless:  I always like to use graphs to support analysis.  But it is also important to know how much can be worked out without the use of computational aids.  (I tell students to work out the overall picture as much as possible "by hand", and "bring in the machines" for the heavy or precision work...)